# vector destructor error for matrix multiplication function c++

Tags: c++, vector, destructor

I wanted to define a function for matrix multiplication. The operation is performed and result matrix is built but in the end of main function I have an error in stl_vector.h.

first try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix_multiplication(std::vector<std::vector<int>> &a, std::vector<std::vector<int>> &b, size_t n){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> res ( n );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
            int sum = 0;
            for ( size_t k = 0; k < n; k++ ) {
                sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
            res[i].push_back( sum );
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> aaa(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < aaa.size(); ++i) {
        aaa[i].assign ( aaa.size(), 1 );
    }

    vector<vector<int>> bbb(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < bbb.size(); ++i) {
        bbb[i].assign ( bbb.size(), 2 );
    }

    std::cout << bbb.size();

    matrix_multiplication(aaa,bbb,aaa.size());
}
```

second try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix_multiplication(std::vector<std::vector<int>> &a, std::vector<std::vector<int>> &b, size_t n){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> res ( n );
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        res[i].assign ( n, 0 );
    }
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
            int sum = 0;
            for ( size_t k = 0; k < n; k++ ) {
                sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
            res[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> aaa(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < aaa.size(); ++i) {
        aaa[i].assign ( aaa.size(), 1 );
    }

    vector<vector<int>> bbb(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < bbb.size(); ++i) {
        bbb[i].assign ( bbb.size(), 2 );
    }

    std::cout << bbb.size();

    matrix_multiplication(aaa,bbb,aaa.size());
}
```

when I run this code:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

and when I debug code, it stucks in this line (in stl_vector.h).

```
 ~vector() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { std::_Destroy(this->_M_impl._M_start, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
              _M_get_Tp_allocator()); } (this line)
```

Comment: You can simplify initialization to: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> aaa(4, std::vector<int>(4, 1));`

Comment: Listen your compiler (or upgrade warning level): *warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]*.

Comment: Once fixed, no more crashes [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ed4f022899e7c7a).

Comment: Unrelated, but a vector of vectors is only a matrix **if all row vectors have same size**. And on a mathematical point of view, the matrix product is defined for a matrix (n,m) by a matrix (m, p) and the result as a matrix (n, p). Said differently you should not have to pass the `n`  parameter.

Comment: You're right! The function has no return. Resolved!

Comment: @Serge Ballesta   Thank you